# How to survive the curse-frogs in Dark Souls?

Tags: dark-souls

I am in the depths, fell down a hole and died to a curse when three frog things pounced. Is there a way to block the fog, or do you just have to kill them before they burp it up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fog is unblockable, those frogs are nasty, I got so scared the first time I feel down that hole (there are several btw).

I don't know if they are accessible at that time, but Paladin armor and Cursebite ring helps out A LOT! Also, humanity and being in human form improves your curse defence (meaning that the meter takes longer to fill up).

They have two methods of fogging you:

Either they stay stationary and you can clearly see that they are inhaling, in order to exhale their weird fog. This is the best time to attack them, attack them from the side while they are charging up their attack.

I don't think that they will trace you once they started the animation (that is, it will face the same direction during the whole animation).

Alternately, they do a nasty jumping attack, which has a somewhat longer range. It can be kind of tricky in the way that they kind of spit out a projectile of fog, which expands around it's point of origin. Just take note where their projectile landed, and move away.

Mobility is the key here.

Remember, it's always easier with one monster at a time.

If they got you, that means that you are cursed, and that means that now is a great time to farm the frogs (I think they are called Basilisk), since getting cursed a second time won't do anything (unless you lifted the curse status, which you can do by going to the tower where you rang the first bell, and talk to the black clad NPC standing close the ladder leading up, residing in the room you enter directly after defeating the Gargoyles and buying a curse stone from him, OR by buying it (curse stone) from the dead lady behind the grates in the aqueduct between Lower Undead Burg and Firelink Shrine). 
Find the bonfire in the Sewers, and then go down the stairs to the right, then climb down the ladder into the cage (inside the same room where the giant rat was), go out of the cage and walk down the stairs and then go left, trailing the waterway. If you go the right way, you should be attacked by some giant rats before you find the frogs.

Good luck, and don't let them get to you.

Comment: Nice answer, comprehensive and helpful. I shall attempt to take them down soon.

Comment: In the original version of Dark Souls (pre-patches), curses stacked. That means you could go from 1/2 health to 1/4 health, then 1/8 health etc if you kept getting cursed over and over. Aren't we glad it isn't like that anymore!

Comment: I did not know that. That's harsh, though I kind of like it better. When I was farming the frogs, before Gaping Dragon (?), and occasionally got cursed again, I was a bit disappointed in that it was no punishment. I am glad that they got the giant rats before the frogs, so that you really feel that your hp is halved, they got me more times than the frogs, due to the curse.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Apeforce's answer, there is a ring in the new londo ruins at the very end where the ladder to the top of the church is. On the bottom floor behind the building off to a ledge there is an item. A ghost ambushes you when you try to take it but the ring gives you around 100+ curse resistance making you basically immune to curse while wearing it. I have personally basked in the awful curse gas of the frogs and had nothing happen to me using that ring.

In case you don't know, to kill ghosts you need to be either A: Actually cursed or B: Use a transient curse item (You get three at the start of new londo from a corpse). After that you're free to kill ghosts who drop more of the item.

It's a fairly hazardous journey but once you know the path and all the ghost ambushes, you can easily grab the ring and enjoy immunity from curse.

Comment: I don't know if I am up for new londo yet - it just about takes it out of me when I (am forced to) take on more than one zombie dog, let alone ghosts - but the freedom from curses sounds great.

Comment: It is very dangerous unless you're use to it, even then I can die a few times before I get the ring if I try to rush through. Fair warning though, that church is CRAWLING with ghosts. At least 10+

Comment: not entirely sure as i haven't played the game in a while, but isn't the holy sword (that you can find in front of an undead dragon out on the cliffs, as well as a shield and something else) able to kill ghosts, or am i just remembering that incorrectly? i know it is extremely useful in the catacombs since if you play the rogue(?) you can get to it very early with the universal lockpick thingie. also note that you can get to the cliffs via the same area you go to to get to the ruins.

Comment: I know divine weapons don't inherently kill ghosts (I main a dex/faith user). That specific weapon may have special attributes. No idea.